# React ag grid conditional cellrenderer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I want the props cellRenderer: 'agGroupCellRenderer' work conditionally.
ex,

```
{
      headerName: 'testname',
      valueGetter: params => {
        return .....;
      },
      cellRenderer: 'agGroupCellRenderer',
      cellRendererParams: {
        suppressCount: true,
      },
}
```

if params.data.type==='group', then cellRenderer: 'agGroupCellRenderer', otherwise, cellRenderer:''(just do not render it as group).

I did something like

```
cellRenderer: params => {
        return params.data.group=== 'Y' ? cellRenderer:'agGroupCellRenderer' : '';
      },
```

but it just returns the string 'agGroupCellRenderer'

Answer (score 2):

You have defined your own cellRender function, so the AG-Grid will use the value you returned.

Maybe you can do something like this

```
cellRenderer: params => {
    params.data.group=== 'Y' ? cellRenderer: params.colDef.cellRenderer = 'agGroupCellRenderer' : '';
},
```

Comment: when my condition is false, what cellRenderer should I specify ? because when the condition evaluation falls back to the empty string '', the cell becomes empty and my field does not show anymore. I can't seem to find the default value for the cellRenderer